# Recovery of a virtual machine (Centos, Windows, Oracle Virtual Box)

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

By mistake, I have deleted all files in my `c:\linux\` folder where I had `wmdk` files corresponding to a virtual machine. Fortunately, there were in the recycle bin and I simply recovered them. Unfortunately, it does not work. When I try to run the VM, I get:

```
Could not open the medium 'C:\linux\CentOS.vmdk'.
VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'C:\linux\CentOS.vmdk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
MediumWrap
Interface: 
IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
```

My impression was that the file is corrupted or not present. However, the file `C:\linux\CentOS.vmdk` is there and has - according to my opinion - a reasonable content:

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=0321818e
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"

# Extent description
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s001.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s002.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s003.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s004.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s005.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s006.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s007.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s008.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s009.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s010.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s011.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s012.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s013.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s014.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s015.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s016.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s017.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s018.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s019.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s020.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s021.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s022.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s023.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s024.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s025.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s026.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s027.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s028.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s029.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s030.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s031.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s032.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s033.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s034.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s035.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s036.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s037.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s038.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s039.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "CentOS-s040.vmdk"
RW 81920 SPARSE "CentOS-s041.vmdk"

# The disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
ddb.adapterType="ide"
ddb.uuid.image="b0d20de5-8ca5-4452-8534-9f9889286721"
ddb.uuid.parent="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.modification="589d249a-6e74-472d-941e-0787a39e7cca"
ddb.uuid.parentmodification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.geometry.cylinders="16383"
ddb.geometry.heads="16"
ddb.geometry.sectors="63"
ddb.geometry.biosCylinders="1024"
ddb.geometry.biosHeads="255"
ddb.geometry.biosSectors="63"
```

I am using

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Oracle VM Virtual Box 5.0.12

So far tried:
- To restart the virtual box
- To restart the computer

Thank you for any help.

Comment: make a copy of the vdmk file and try vmware player works just like virtual box and its free also

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a copy of the *.vmdk and then attaching it to a new VM.

This reminds me of issues I have had previously where a virtual disk has been changed and the VM config no longer recognises it. (My previous issues were GUID mismatches).